# using focus on textBox

Tags: c#, asp.net, textbox, focus

Using a TextBox I need to insert an ID number, when the Focus is off the textbox, according to the ID number I need to select certain information from a database. How can I check whether the focus is on the textbox?

Comment: Show your work first..

Comment: i dont know how to use focus method..how can i show you the work?

Comment: Do you want to `focus` the `textbox` when it is not in `focus`?

Comment: no, i want to know when the user get out of focus from the textbox so I can use the string he wrotes in the textBox and give him some data

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**1.** You can use `Enter` Event for identifying the `Focus Gain` of the `TextBox` control.
**2.** You can use `Leave` Event for identifying the `Focus Lost` of the `TextBox` control.

Try This:

```
        this.textBox1.Enter += new System.EventHandler(this.textBox1_Enter);
        this.textBox1.Leave += new System.EventHandler(this.textBox1_Leave);

        private void textBox1_Enter(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            //TextBox gained Focus
        }

        private void textBox1_Leave(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
             //TextBox Lost Focus
        }
```

In your case if you want to get the records based on given `ID` when user `leaves` the `TextBox` try the following `sample code`.

**Step1:** Subscribe to the `Leave` event of the `TextBox` control as below:

```
this.textBox1.Leave += new System.EventHandler(this.textBox1_Leave);
```

**Step2:** now write the function which will handle the `Leave Event` (`textBox1_Leave`).

```
private void textBox1_Leave(object sender, EventArgs e)
{

//your Leave event handling code here

}
```

**Complete Code:**  (sample code)

```
            this.textBox1.Leave += new System.EventHandler(this.textBox1_Leave);
            private void textBox1_Leave(object sender, EventArgs e)
            {
            SqlConnection scon= new SqlConnection("connection string here");
            String strcmd="seect * from products where ID=@ID";//change your query asper your need.
            SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand(strcmd,scon);

            cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@ID", textBox1.Text);

            scon.Open();

             SqlDataReader sreader=cmd.ExecuteReader();
             while(sreader.Read())
             {
             //do whatever you want with data
             }
            scon.Close();
            }
```

Comment: can u explain please what you did?

Comment: @user2922456: see my edited answer, still you want more please let me know.

Comment: I cant understand this line :             this.textBox1.Leave += new System.EventHandler(this.textBox1_Leave);

Comment: @user2922456: basicall that is a statement where you have to subscribe to the Leave event so that you willbe notified when ever Leave event on Textbox1 happens. you can simply open properties ->events of Textbox control and double click on `Leave` event so that Visual studio adds that line for you :)